# Difference between defining variable as var $a=$() and var a?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style

Sometimes in JQuery we define variable as `var $a=$()` which is like declaring a function. So i want to know does it make any change if we define variable as `var a` only?

Comment: Do you just mean "without the $ symbol"? If so, then it makes no difference, it's just a convention used to sometimes indicate that you're using a jQuery object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean:

```
var a = $(/* Object or Selector gets passed here */)
```

Then the only difference would be the name. Developers use `$a` to indicate that the value is already `jQuery`-ied. Leaving it off changes no functionality but would be a dis-service to future developers.

Comment: $() is a shortcut for the jQuery function. It is either passed an object or a selector. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 2):

no, it is no different. `$a` is the same as `a` in that context. It's simply a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

Generally I prefer naming jQuery objects prepended with a $ sign.. It's a convention to recognize jQuery objects in your code..

But it's just another variable name ;;

```
var a = 2;
var $a = $('#something');
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically this is an allowed violation of [Crockford's coding convention](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) for javascript. It is used to differentiate jQuery objects from javascript DOM elements.

E.g.

```
var a = document.getElementById('a'); // DOM element
var $a = $(a); // jQuery object for the DOM element with ID 'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

$ is an allowed character in JS identifiers, it makes no difference. $(obj) wraps the object obj with a jQuery object, and decorates obj with a lot of additional behavior.

These are legal Javascript variable names:

```
$a=1;
a$$$=1;
$a=1;
```

The function $ is an alias for jQuery, if you do something like:

your HTML:

```
<img src='logo.png' id='site_logo'/>
```

your JS:

```
var logo = $('#site_logo');
logo.fadeOut();
```

The method fadeOut doesn't belongs to the img element, but to the jQuery wrapper.